Blackjack em C - Meu jogo está fechando sozinho no trecho final do código
Estou criando um jogo de Blackjack (21) porém ao chegar no trecho onde determina-se o vencedor do jogo o terminal onde o jogo está sendo executado é fechado.
Notei que isso ocorre apenas quando há pelo menos um jogador na partida, se apenas a CPU jogar o código corre perfeitamente.
Executando o código pelo site Replit ficará mais fácil de identificar o erro.
Espero que possam me ajudar, ficarei grato. Segue abaixo o trecho que provavelmente está ocorrendo o bug:
Se forem necessários mais detalhes pode verificar o código no github: Repositório
// Ordenar jogadores pela pontuação
              qsort(jogador, qtdjogador, sizeof(Jogador), compararPontuacao);

              // Exibir resultados
              printf("Resultado final:\n");
              for (int i = 0; i < qtdjogador; i++) {
                if (jogador[i].pontuacao == -1) {
                  printf("%s foi eliminado!\n", jogador[i].nome);
                } else {
                  printf("%d. %s (Pontuação: %d)\n", i + 1, jogador[i].nome,
                         jogador[i].pontuacao);
                  for (int j = 0; j < jogador[i].numCartas; j++) {
                    imprimirCartaASCII(jogador[i].mao[j]);
                  }
                }
                printf("\n");
              }

              // Determinar o vencedor ou empate
              int maxPontuacao = jogador[0].pontuacao;
              int countEmpate = 0;
              for (int i = 1; i < qtdjogador; i++) {
                if (jogador[i].pontuacao == maxPontuacao) {
                  countEmpate++;
                }
              }

              if (countEmpate > 0) {
                printf("O jogo terminou em empate entre %d jogadores com pontuação %d!\n", countEmpate + 1, maxPontuacao);
              } else if (strcmp(jogador[0].nome, "CPU") != 0 && jogador[0].pontuacao != -1) {
                printf("O vencedor é %s com pontuação %d!\n", jogador[0].nome,
                       jogador[0].pontuacao);
              } else if (jogador[0].pontuacao != -1) {
                printf("A CPU venceu o jogo com pontuação %d!\n", jogador[0].pontuacao);
              } else {
                printf("Todos os jogadores humanos foram eliminados. A CPU venceu o jogo!\n");
              }

              printf("Aperte qualquer tecla para fechar...");
              getchar();
              return 0;
            }


Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada - melhorias devem ser feitas lá).
